# C++/Java recursion variable initialize

Tags: java, c++, variables, global-variables, extern

I wonder why this C++ code is valid and doesn't cause any errors:

```
extern int B;
int A = B;
int B = A;

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", B);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

First, the variable `A` will be created in some memory address, then its value will be initialized from variable `B`, but then variable `B` goes back to initialize its value from variable `A`, and so on, ...
So, why is there no infinity loop or any error here?
The program still runs ok, and the value of `B` is 0

This is valid for Java as well:

```
class A {
    static final int AA = B.BB;
}

class B {
    static final int BB = A.AA;
}
```

Any one can explain these questions for me, thanks!

Comment: Be careful here. Even if the code might seem similar and *seem* to behave in a similar way, Java and C++ are still very different languages and might in reality behave very differently for otherwise similar code.

Comment: Heck, this is an area where C and C++ start to differ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I am answering this for C++. Although the story might not be all that different for Java*

It is not an infinite loop because everything is resolved at compile time, and here is how:

- The compiler sees that `B` is declared as `extern`
- The linker knows that `A` has to be set to the value of whatever `B` is supposed to be when it is declared, so setting the value of `A` is delayed until much later
- `B` is finally declared but since it is not assigned a value, it gets a default value of `0`.
- The linker finally resolves the value of `A` and can now set it to `0` as well.
- Compiler compiles your program and the output is `0`

---

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28734780/2089675) for more details

Comment: "B is finally declared but since it is not assigned a value". 
So, does it mean that `B` will looking for `A` but it see that `A` is delayed waiting for something else, so `B` will ignore init from `A` and set from default value (0) ?

Comment: @user2447581 this will be going into details of how the compiler works, but essentially once the value of `B` is discovered to refer to itself, then I believe the compiler will detect a cycle in internal graph it uses to keep track of what variables are used where, and when it does it will break the cycle and use the default value of `B` which `A` then gets

Answer (score 4):

Since I´m not familiar with c++ I can only explain it to you with the java example.

I think this might explain the issue:

```
class A {
    static final int AA = B.BB;
}

class B {
    static final int BB = A.AA;
}
```

- A.AA gets initialized with value 0
- A.AA looks for B.BB
- B.BB gets initialized with value 0
- B.BB looks for A.AA
- At this time A.AA already has the value zero (default value of int), so B.BB becomes 0.
- A.AA becomes 0

Comment: Java variables start with a default value and are then assigned +1

Comment: thanks for your explanation about Java (still, I can't make 2 acceptances for 2 answer, sorry for that :)).

Comment: So, the main key is that if a variable (`BB`) is looking for another (`AA`), there are 2 cases: **1.**_if `AA` is not initalized_, it will init this variable with default value, looking for assign value if have and assign back to `BB`. **2.**_if `AA` is already initalized_, it will assign back the value of `AA`, no matter if `AA` is looking for someother or not

Comment: `no matter if AA is looking for someother or not` I´d rather say, that the compiler doesn´t recognize or even care if AA still is looking fo a value, it just finds the current value of AA, which is 0.